# Using func() in seperate class requires instance of the class that owns the method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function, func

Sorry if this is a stupid question but when I try to use a function in another class it requires an instance of the class that owns it.

```
class Economy {

    let configuration = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    func setBalance(amount: Double) {
        configuration.setDouble(getBalance(), forKey: "balance")
    }

    func getBalance() -> Double {
        return configuration.doubleForKey("balance")
    }
}
```

When I use the getBalance() method in the setBalance method it works fine but when I use it to define a variable that isn't in a method or use it in another class I have to do:
getBalance(self: Economy)
instead of just
getBalance()

I'm not sure if this is a problem or what but how can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds about right, Whats the problem?

Comment: Which `Economy` do you wish to get the balance of? Since `Economy` is a class, you could have many instances (many different economies). If you can have only one, make the class a singleton - but you'll still have to specify the instance...

Comment: I just want a way to be able to use the methods. @Grimxn
I think my problem is that I don't know how to properly use a function.
Would I be right to assume that?

Comment: It looks like you are using a class when you should be using a naked function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks, from your comments, as if you don't really want a class (with different instances) at all : "I just want a way to be able to use the methods". This is not usual in classes - usually, a class instance holds its own unique state information. In your case, though, *all* instances will hold the same state (the `standardUserDefaults`).

There are two ways to do what you want - use a [singleton](http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton), or, more simply, use naked functions:

```
func setBalance(amount: Double) {
    let configuration = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    configuration.setDouble(getBalance(), forKey: "balance")
}

func getBalance() -> Double {
    let configuration = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    return configuration.doubleForKey("balance")
}
```

note, these are outside any class. Then you simply say

```
setBalance(15)
print("\(getBalance()") // prints 15
```

note also that there is no need for these to be functions. You could equally validly say

```
var balance: Double {
    set {
        let configuration = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        configuration.setDouble(getBalance(), forKey: "balance")
    }
    get { 
        let configuration = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        return configuration.doubleForKey("balance")
    }
}
```

in which case

```
balance = 15
print("\(balance") // prints 15
```